# specs2 with Play : Better placeholder than "1 mustEqual 1"?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, specs2

When writing specs2 tests for Play framework, when trying to do this:

```
object SingleTest extends PlaySpecification {
  "logging in" should {
    "fail with bad credentials" in {
      1 mustEqual 1
    }
  }
}
```

In scala we're spoiled to use "???" for anything not implemented yet. But when I tried to do that it throws this error:

```
Error:(28, 37) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.specs2.main.CommandLineAsResult[Unit]
"fail with bad credentials" in ...
```

Is there a way around this, or should I just get used to "1 mustEqual 1"?

Thanks.

Comment: actually, seems like "true" works as well, guess that's the best alternative?

Comment: You could also use `ok`.

Comment: not sure if it happens on specs2 or scalatest (i always confuse both), but there's a pending and a fail statement that can receive a string (a reason). maybe it's not called pending/fail on specs2, but it should offer something similar

Answer (score 1):

you can also use success and failure keywords

```
"logging in" should {
    "fail with bad credentials" in {
        success
    }

   "another option for login" in  {
      failure("not implemented") 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.5/org.specs2.guide.PendingUntilFixedExamples.html), you need to use `pendingUntilFixed`.  So, using your code:

```
object SingleTest extends PlaySpecification {
  "logging in" should {
    "fail with bad credentials" in {
      1 mustEqual 1
    }.pendingUntilFixed
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess ok + .pendingUntilFixed is the best combo then?

Comment: depends what you are trying to make it best for.  `pendingUntilFixed` gives other eyes looking at the code that this test isn;t being run on purpose.  Using `ok`(which I'm not familiar with), doesn't really tell me whats going on with the test.  E.g. are they removing the functionality associated with the test?  Are they just doing a quick, make it pending, type of thing?

I'd go with `pendingUntilFixed` because it leaves no ambiguity about what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Use `todo` like so:

```
object SingleTest extends PlaySpecification {
  "logging in" should {
    "fail with bad credentials" >> todo
  }
}
```